# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException error when navigating to another page in Xamarin forms app using OnAppearing() to reload

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I have this HostOffices.xaml.cs page below which allows a host to view a list of offices using a Listview, and allows the host to select an office, as well as navigate to a page for adding a new office or editing an existing office. The navigation to the EditOffice page used to work fine, however after including the OnAppearing function to set the binding context to a new instance of HostOfficesVM, the app throws a 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' error when I click on an office in the list to try to navigate to the EditOffice page.

I used a try/catch block in the OfficesView_SelectionChanged method to better understand the error and it says: exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
I also set a breakpoint to the 'OfficesView_SelectionChanged' async void method and stepped into the app shell routing to my 'EditOffice' page. This redirected me to my 'EditOfficeVM' ViewModel which calls a 'LoadOffice()' function. It seems this is where the error is thrown because when I step into that, the error pops up at the 3rd line of the function ('Location = selectedOffice.Location;)

Clicking the details of the exception shows errors (see attached screenshot) in the [TargetSite-->Declaring Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdtvy.png) as well as the [InnerException-->base-->base-->TargetSite-->Declaring type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozs7T.png).

Any ideas on how to solve the error from here??
The referred scripts are shown below:

HostOffices.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Teamworks_2.ViewModels;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Teamworks_2.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HostOffices : ContentPage
    {
        ViewModels.HostOfficesVM hostofficesvm;
        //Make reference to the global class
        App globalref = (App)Application.Current;

        public HostOffices()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            hostofficesvm = new ViewModels.HostOfficesVM();
            BindingContext = hostofficesvm;
        }

        private async void OfficesView_SelectionChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CurrentSelection != null)
            {
                globalref.SelectedOffice = hostofficesvm.SelectedOffice;
                //Models.Office thisoffice = e.CurrentSelection[0];
                //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(BookNow)}?{nameof(ViewModels.BookNowVM.CurrentOffice)}={officesvm.SelectedOffice}");
                try
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("EditOffice");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "An error occurred while navigating to the EditOffice page: " + ex.Message, "OK");
                }
            }
        }

        void OfficesView_ItemSelected(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("AddOffice");
        }
        //private async void MainMovieView_SelectionChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

        //{
        //    if (e.CurrentSelection != null)
        //    {
        //        globalref.SelectedOffice = SelectedOffice;
        //        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new OfficeDetails()));
        //    }
        //}

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            this.BindingContext = new HostOfficesVM();
        }
    }
}
```

EditOfficeVM.cs (showing LoadOffice definition and declaration)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace Teamworks_2.ViewModels
{
    public class EditOfficeVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Services.Database DBInstance = new Services.Database();

        App globalref = (App)Application.Current;

        public EditOfficeVM()
        {
            LoadOffice();
        }
    
     public void LoadOffice()
        {
            Models.Office selectedOffice = globalref.SelectedOffice;
            Office_name = selectedOffice.Name;
            Location = selectedOffice.Location;
            Num_guests = selectedOffice.NumGuests;
            Sqft = selectedOffice.Sqft;
            Description = selectedOffice.Description;
            pricePerhour = selectedOffice.Hourly;
            MinHours = selectedOffice.MinHours;
            Amenities = selectedOffice.Amenities;
            Features = selectedOffice.Features;
        }
```

I was expecting to navigate to my EditOffice page, which used to work fine. However, after adding the Onappearing() function to refresh the ListView with the newly added office, a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException is thrown when I try to navigate to the EditOffice page.

Comment: you need to look at the InnerException and step through the code in OnAppearing to find the root cause

Comment: Hi @Jason I have just had a look at the InnerException but still do not understand the root causes displayed. Please refer to the updated post with attached photos.

Comment: This is a Null Reference exception.  You are trying to reference an object that does not have a value.  Most likely caused by globalRef.SelectedOffice